# "-ErrorAction Stop" not working in try/catch

Tags: powershell, error-handling

It was working just fine yesterday.

```
try {
    tabadmin ziplogs -f -p -a -l -n -ErrorAction Stop
} catch {
    backupemail
    [System.Environment]::Exit(1)
}
```

Today when I run this it brings up the "Zip up log files to the specific file" and lists all the possible command options. I already pointed out `-f -p -a -l`.

If I purposely change ziplogs to "zipylooog" it will point that error out with no email sent.

If I get rid of `-ErrorAction Stop` it runs perfect.

Comment: you appear to have an additional - after the -f

Comment: What Leon said... Anything after the f switch is being ignored because of the typo.

Comment: that was my typo i included in here. not for the actual script. Its just not liking the -ErrorAction stop for whatever reason

Comment: You are feeding the ErrorAction parameter to the tabadmin command. Try using Start-Process to start a process OR set the $erroraction variable before running the command.

Comment: Tried running it before and it said its an UNknown Command.  this script with less words than a tweet is destroying me.

Comment: Is tabadmin a PowerShell cmdlet or a native command?

Answer (score 0):

- **`-ErrorAction`** is a [*common parameter*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-erroraction) and as such **only supported by *PowerShell* commands**, specifically by *cmdlets* and their written-in-PowerShell equivalents, [advanced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) functions/scripts.
- When calling an *external program*, `-ErrorAction Stop` has *no special meaning* and simply passes these two arguments to that program, which typically causes the call to *fail* (as happened in your case, where `tabadmin` didn't recognize an `-ErrorAction` parameter and showed its syntax help as a result).
- Up to at least PowerShell (Core) 7.3.x, you cannot trap failures reported by external programs with a [`try` / `catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) statement.<sup>[1]</sup>

  - Instead, check the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode) for a nonzero value to detect failure, and take action manually.

---

Therefore, use the following; the only reason for `try` / `catch` use is to also handle the case where `tabadmin` *cannot even be invoked* (typically because its directory isn't listed in `$env:PATH`):

```bash
try {
    # Do NOT use -ErrorAction Stop with external programs.
    tabadmin ziplogs -f -p -a -l -n
    if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) { 
      # `tabadmin` indicated failure via its exit code.
      # Use `throw` to transfer control to the `catch` block.
      throw 
    } 
} catch {
    backupemail
    [System.Environment]::Exit(1)
}
```

---

<sup>[1] See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67743340/45375) for details, including a *potential* future, opt-in feature that may change this.</sup>