# How To Get Exit Code From PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell, error-handling, try-catch, exit-code

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script which sends a Slack notification whenever our build system in unable to push Docker images to Docker Hub.  How can I detect and handle the `Process exited with code 1` from the `docker push` command?  I've tried the following, but the `catch` block isn't called.

```
try {
  docker push $dockerImage;
}catch{
  #Send error details to Slack
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell and process exit codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57468522/powershell-and-process-exit-codes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- In *Windows PowerShell* and [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) *up to version 7.3.x*, **calls to *external programs* (such as `docker`) *never* cause a statement-terminating error**<sup>[1]</sup> that you can trap with [`try` / `catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally); similarly, ***stderr* output from external program is (rightfully) *not* considered *error* output** by PowerShell, and therefore `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` has no effect on it (for *legacy exceptions* in *Windows PowerShell*, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74382502/45375)).

  - In **PowerShell (Core) *v7.4+*, *opt-in* integration with PowerShell's error handling is available**, via the [`$PSNativeCommandUseErrorActionPreference` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#psnativecommanduseerroractionpreference).

    - If you set this variable to `$true`, any external-program call that reports a *nonzero exit code* *automatically* triggers a *PowerShell* error in response (obviating the need for explicit `$LASTEXITCODE -ne 0` checks), which then integrates with PowerShell's own error handling.<sup>[2]</sup>
      That is, with the [`$ErrorActionPreference` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#erroractionpreference) set to `'Stop'`, any external program reporting a nonzero exit code will then result in a *script-terminating* (fatal by default) error.
  - In general, note that **a statement-terminating PowerShell error** (which *can* be caught with `try` / `catch`) ***does* occur if PowerShell fails to even *launch* a command**, such as when you supply a *non-existent* executable name or path; e.g.:

    ```bash
    try   { nosuchexe foo bar }
    catch { Write-Warning "Failed to invoke nosuchexe: $_" }
    ```
- The **[automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode)** reflects the **process exit code** of the most recently executed external program. By convention, **exit code `0` signals success, anything else an error condition**.

Therefore:

```bash
docker push $dockerImage
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
  #Send error details to Slack
}
```

See also:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57468523/45375) has more information on exit-code processing in PowerShell.

---

<sup>[1] The only exception is a *bug*, present in *Windows PowerShell* and historically in PowerShell (Core) up to the no-longer-supported v7.1.x, where the combination of *redirecting stderr output* (`2>` or `*>`) with `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` unexpectedly causes a *script*-terminating error if there's actual stderr output - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66726535/45375).</sup>

<sup>[2] Unfortunately, up at least PowerShell 7.4.0-preview.6, the automatically triggered PowerShell error is a *non-terminating* error rather than a *statement-terminating* one; the latter would make more sense, as it would allow it to be *selectively* caught with a [`try`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) statement - see [GitHub issue #18368](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18368).</sup>

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea have large random pos/neg numbers as failing result codes from `$LASTEXITCODE.

Comment: @not2qubit, indeed, small, positive numbers are _typical_, and, for cross-platform use you're limited to positive numbers between `0` and `255`. Technically, however, process exit codes on Windows can be any signed 32-bit integer value (`[int]`/ `System.Int32`, in PowerShell / .NET terms).