# How to stop powershell script when error occurs?

Tags: powershell

I have a "main" powershell script that executes multiple scripts that install apps on a VM. I'm trying to implement the error control on the main script, meaning:

**If one of the scripts that installs the apps fails, the rest of the scripts aren't executed.**

Here is my main script:

```
try{
    powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File 'C:\\TEST\\Scripts\\App1.ps1'    
    powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File 'C:\\TEST\\Scripts\\App2.ps1'    
    powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File 'C:\\TEST\\Scripts\\App3.ps1'    
 
}catch
{
  Write-Host "Error"

}
```

Here is an example of one of the scripts (App2.ps1) that installs the apps (all the scripts follow the same logic as this one)

```
#Set logging 
$logFile = "C:\TEST\Logs\" + (get-date -format 'yyyyMMdd') + '_softwareinstall.log'
function Write-Log {
    Param($message)
    Write-Output "$(get-date -format 'yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss') $message" | Out-File -Encoding utf8 $logFile -Append
}


#Install APP2 
$file = Test-Path "C:\TEST\Apps\APP2\APP2 x64 7.2.1.msi"
if($file)
{
   try{
        Write-Log "Installing App2"
        Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/i "C:\TEST\Apps\APP2\App2 x64 7.2.1.msi" ALLUSERS=1 AddLocal=MiniDriver,PKCS,UserConsole,Troubleshooting,Help /qn /norestart' 
        if(Test-Path -Path "C:\Program Files\HID Global\APP2\ac.app2.exe")
        {
            Write-Log "App2 installed"
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Log "There was a problem while installing App2"
        throw "There was a problem while installing App2"
        }
    }catch
    {
        Write-Log "[ERROR] There was a problem while starting the installation for App2"
        throw "[ERROR] There was a problem while starting the installation for App2"
    }
}
else
{
     Write-Log "Installation file for App2 not found"
     throw "Installation file for App2 not found"
}
```

Here is the output:
[image]

**(I blured the names of the apps for confidential purposes)**

Why did the main script continue to execute when the script to install the APP2 through an exception?
Shouldn't have stopped and shown the message written on the catch section in the main script?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try adding `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` to the beginning of your script

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much. I didn't know it was something that simple

Comment: Good deal. Glad to help.

Comment: As an aside: ``\`` has no special meaning in PowerShell, so it never needs to be escaped as ``\\``; for instance, `C:\TEST\Scripts\App1.ps1` works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

As recommended I added `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`to the beginning of my script

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

try{
    powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File 'C:\\TEST\\Scripts\\APP1.ps1'    
    powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File 'C:\\TEST\\Scripts\\APP2.ps1'    
    powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File 'C:\\TEST\\Scripts\\APP3.ps1'    
 
}catch
{
  Write-Host "Error"

}
```

And the output it's just the message "Error", indicated in the catch section.

Thank you to [@Doug Maurer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4085331/doug-maurer)

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

If you really need to call your `.ps1` scripts via `powershell.exe` (instead of just invoking them directly, in-process), `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` is generally *not* enough if you combine with a `powershell.exe -File` call; instead, call via a *script block* (`{ ... }`):

```bash
# Make any PowerShell error abort the script.
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

try {
  'C:\TEST\Scripts\App1.ps1', 
  'C:\TEST\Scripts\App1.ps2', 
  'C:\TEST\Scripts\App1.ps3' |
    ForEach-Object {
      # Note: This relies on *error* output from the scripts
      #       to trigger the catch block.
      powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted { & $args[0] } -args $_
    }
}
catch {
  Write-Host Error
}
```

---

As of this writing, **[your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74363190/45375), which relies on the presence of *stderr* output, is *not* effective - *except* in the following contexts**:

- In the **obsolescent, Windows PowerShell-only ISE**, which is best avoided these days:

  - The Windows PowerShell ISE is [no longer actively developed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell (Core) 6+. The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).
- In ***Windows PowerShell* only**, in the context of ***remoting* calls** as well as locally when a **`2>` redirection** is used.

That it works in these specific cases **relies on *undesirable* behavior, which has been fixed in [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**:

- In the cases above, *stderr* output from *external programs* is inappropriately routed through PowerShell's *error* [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams), even though **stderr output cannot be assumed to represent *errors*** (it is often used for status or progress messages - anything *other than data*; the only reliable indicator of whether an external program failed is its process *exit code*).
- It is this inappropriate routing through PowerShell's error stream that makes stderr output susceptible to `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`

---

**Taking a step back**:

- ***From PowerShell*, there's rarely a need to call its own CLI**, [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) (in the case of *Windows PowerShell*), which requires creating another PowerShell instance as a child process, which is not only expensive, but also means that any output is received as *text* only, forgoing PowerShell's rich support for .NET data types (except, with limitations, if you use a script block - see below).

  - Usually, you'd **simply invoke `.ps1` files *directly***, for efficient *in-process* execution; e.g., , as a stand-alone statement, `C:\TEST\Scripts\App1.ps1`
  - **If you do need to call via PowerShell's CLI** (which situationally may be the respective *other* PowerShell edition's CLI), **you'll get the best integration with using a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`)**, which uses behind-the-scenes serialization and deserialization, with the child session's PowerShell-specific output streams mapped to the calling one's, so that `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` acts the same way it would if you called the script in-process; e.g., `powershell.exe { C:\TEST\Scripts\App1.ps1 }`; additionally, the serialization/deserialization tries to preserve *data types* [as much as possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375).

---

**Considerations for *external programs* in general**:

- As stated, success vs. failure should *not* be inferred from the presence of stderr output in an external-program call.
- Instead, by (widely observed) convention, external programs signal success vs. failure via their process *exit code*: `0` for success, any *nonzero* value for failure.
- PowerShell reflects the exit code of the most recently executed external program in its [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode).

**Up to at least PowerShell (Core) 7.3, you'll therefore need to check  `$LASTEXITCODE -ne 0` after every external-program call** in order to detect failure (in *PowerShell (Core) 7.2+*, you may alternatively use **`-not $?`** *immediately* after the call (as well as `&&` and `||`, the [pipeline-chain operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipeline_Chain_Operators)), but in *Windows PowerShell* that doesn't work reliably, due to the `2>` redirection bug mentioned above).

This is cumbersome, and a future PowerShell (Core) version may make this easier - see next section.

---

***Future* considerations, as of PowerShell (Core) 7.3:**

As of v7.3, there is an [experimental feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Experimental_Features) named `PSNativeCommandErrorActionPreference`, which *may* become an official feature in a future version:

- If this feature is enabled (`Enable-ExperimentalFeature PSNativeCommandErrorActionPreference`) *and* the associated [`$PSNativeCommandErrorActionPreference` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/experimental-features?view=powershell-7.3#psnativecommanderroractionpreference) is set to `$true`, any external-program call that reports a *nonzero exit code* *automatically* triggers a *PowerShell* error in response (obviating the need for explicit `$LASTEXITCODE -ne 0` checks), which then integrates with PowerShell's own error handling.

Unfortunately, as of v7.3.0, the automatically triggered PowerShell error is a *non-terminating* error rather than a *statement-terminating* one; the latter would make more sense, as it would allow it to be *selectively* caught with a [`try`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) statement - see [GitHub issue #18368](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18368).