# Powershell - Why does [ValidateSet("varA", "varB")] not set $LASTEXITCODE?

Tags: powershell, validateset

I wondered that scripts whose parameter are validated by the `ValidateSet` attribute do not return any invalid `$LASTEXITCODE` when invalid parameters are given.

Let's say I have the following PowerShell script, called `try.ps1`:

```
#INPUT Variables for the Script
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [ValidateSet("a", "b")]
    [string] $first_param,

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [ValidateSet("c", "d")]
    [string] $second_param
)

exit 0
```

If I call it now in PS via `PS C:\Users\MyUser> .\try.ps1 -first_param n -second_param c` (invalid `$first_param`) I get a `ParameterBindingValidationException` with an Error called `ParameterArgumentValidationError` but this seems not not set my `$LASTEXITCODE` variable, but why not?

So how is it possible for me (without bloating my code and validating each of my variables in some `if-else` statements to trigger an error) to get `$LASTEXITCODE=1` back when calling my script with invalid params?

Comment: You are never entering the function since the parameter are wrong.  The error has to be caught in the parent method.  Maybe put a try/catch around the call to the function.

Comment: Can you show how you're calling the script?

Comment: If you're calling this script from another script you would wrap the call in a try catch statement as the validation exception is a terminating one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- **Don't rely on *exit codes* for error handling *in PowerShell*; use them to only to communicate success vs. failure *to the outside world***.

  - For scripts you know to be explicitly designed to report an exit code to the outside world, you *can* query `$LASTEXITCODE`, but that alone isn't enough to handle all error conditions, as your example shows.
  - Even then, as discussed in detail in the next section, `$LASTEXITCODE` may contain an *unrelated* value inside a PowerShell session.
- In your invocation attempt, your script doesn't even get to execute, because the parameter-validation failure generates a *statement-terminating error* before the body of your script is entered.

  - When a statement-terminating error occurs, execution *continues* by default.
  - You can query the [automatic `$?` variable (a Boolean success indicator)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#section-1) to see if (at least one) error occurred in the previous statement:

    ```bash
     .\try.ps1 -first_param n -second_param 
     if (-not $?) { # An error occurred
       # Handle the error here.
       # E.g., for a script designed to be called from outside PowerShell:
       exit 2  # Signal failure to an outside caller.
     }
    ```
  - However, by the time you check `$?`, the error message has already *printed* (at least by default); if you want to *intercept* the error, so as to print either no message, a different message, or a modified message, you need a conceptual [`try` / `catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) statement:

    ```bash
     try {
       .\try.ps1 -first_param n -second_param 
     } catch {
       # Handle the error
       # $_ contains the error at hand, as an [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord] instance.
       # E.g., for a script designed to be called from outside PowerShell:
       Write-Error "Invocation of try.ps1 failed unexpectedly: $_"
       exit 2 # Signal failure to an outside caller.
     }
    ```

See also:

- For a comprehensive overview of PowerShell's bewilderingly complex error handling, see [GitHub docs issue #1583](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583).
- For a comprehensive discussion of exit codes in PowerShell, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57468523/45375).

Read on for some additional conceptual information.

---

##### Background information:

Unfortunately, the excerpt from the documentation in [Josef Z's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76163180/45375) is only partly correct (in short: `$LASTEXITODE` *is* set in response to `exit $number` calls in scripts in-session, and `$number` *is* reported as the specific exit code in `-File` CLI calls - [GitHub docs issue #10046](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/10046) aims to get the documentation corrected).
Let me present what I believe to be the correct (bigger) picture:

- PowerShell *itself* does *not* use exit codes for its error handling.
- PowerShell uses exit codes only in order to interact with the *outside world*:

  - It stores the exit code of the most recently executed *external program* (child process) in the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode), so you can check whether it signaled success (exit code `0`) or failure (any *non-zero* exit code, by convention; sometimes, non-zero exit codes are used to communicate *specific success conditions* too; `robocopy.exe` is a notable example).

    - Integration of non-zero exit codes into PowerShell's error handling via a `$PSNativeCommandErrorActionPreference` preference is being considered as of PowerShell 7.3.x; it is currently an *experimental* feature, available in *preview* versions of PowerShell 7.4 - which means that it may or may not become an actual feature - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67743340/45375) for more information.
  - For use in script files(`*.ps1`), PowerShell offers the [`exit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Language_Keywords#exit) keyword so that PowerShell scripts can communicate an exit code *to the outside world* when invoked via PowerShell's CLI ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for PowerShell (Core) 7+)), which is important to signal failure vs. success, particularly in CI/CD environments.
  - The PowerShell CLI's exit-code reporting works differently depending on whether the `-File` or the `-Command` parameter is used (the *default* parameter is `-File` in PowerShell (Core) 7+ vs. `-Command` in *Windows PowerShell*):

    - Note: If a *fatal* (*script*-terminating) error occurs - such as when `throw` is used - both `-File` and `-Command` invocations report `1` as the exit code.
    - With `-File` - for invoking a single `*.ps1` file, optionally with arguments - the exit code is `0` by default, except if explicitly specified via an `exit $number` call in the script, where `$number` represents the desired exit code.
    - With `-Command` - for executing arbitrary PowerShell commands - it is by default the *implied success status* (as it would be reflected in `$?`) of the *last* command in the command string(s) passed to `-Command` that determines the exit code: success is reported as exit code `0`, and failure as `1`

      - Therefore, to explicitly control what exit code is reported in this case, place an `; exit $number` at the end of the `-Command` string(s); if the last (or only) command is a call to an external program or to a script that uses `exit $number` itself, and you want to *relay* that *specific* exit code, use `; exit $LASTEXITCODE`, but note the caveat below.
- While an *intra-session* call to a script (`*.ps1`) that uses `exit` - either *without* an argument or with a numeric argument<sup>[1]</sup> - e.g. `exit 1` - *does* cause PowerShell to set `$LASTEXITCODE` to that value (just `exit` sets `0`), you shouldn't generally rely on that, because:

  - Scripts designed only for intra-session use (for calls from inside a PowerShell session) typically do *not* use `exit`, so `$LASTEXITCODE` won't have a meaningful value, *because it then doesn't get set* - and may therefore reflect an *unrelated* exit code from an *earlier* call to an external program / script.

    - That is, *intra-session* only *explicit* `exit` calls set `$LASTEXITCODE`, not the execution of a script file per se.
    - **Caveat**: If you do *not* use `exit` and your script happens to call an *external program* (or another script that *does* use `exit`) *its* exit code will be reflected in `$LASTEXITCODE` - (a) this may not be your intent and (b) such an incidental exit code is *not* communicated to outside callers via the CLI (see below).
      **Therefore, if your script must reliably report an exit code, make sure that all code paths end with an `exit` or `exit $number` statement**.
  - By contrast, when the CLI is used, with `-File` in the case of a `*.ps1` file, PowerShell defaults to `0` as the exit code (reported to the outside caller) in the absence of an `exit $number` call in the script (`$number` representing the desired exit code).

    - This asymmetry between intra-session and external behavior is the subject of [GitHub issue #11712](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11712).
  - Either way, it is important to note that *for outside callers* it is only ever an *explicit* `exit $number` call in a `*.ps1` file that sets a *non-zero* exit code.

    - This contrasts with POSIX-compatible shells such as `bash`, where, in the absence of `exit`, it is the exit code of the script's *last command* that determines the script's exit code as a whole.

---

<sup>[1] Curiously, `exit` quietly accepts and effectively *ignores* an argument that either isn't numeric or cannot be coerced to a number, so a call such as `exit (Get-Date)` is effectively the same as `exit` and therefore sets `$LASTEXITCODE` / the exit code to `0`</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Described behaviour is well-documented:

### [$LASTEXITCODE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1#lastexitcode)

> Contains the exit code of the last Windows-based program that was run.
> For PowerShell scripts, the value of `$LASTEXITCODE` depends on how
> the script was called and whether the exit keyword was used:
>
> - When a script uses the `exit` keyword, `$LASTEXITCODE` is set to the specified value, regardless of how the script was called. For more
>   information, see [about_Language_Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_keywords?view=powershell-5.1#exit).
> - When a script is called directly, like `./Test.ps1`, or with the call operator (`&`) like `& ./Test.ps1`, **the value of `$LASTEXITCODE`
>   isn't changed**.
> - When a script is called with `powershell.exe` and the `File` parameter, the value of `$LASTEXITCODE` is set to `1` if the script
>   terminated due to a thrown exception and `0` otherwise.

Instead of checking the `$LASTEXITCODE` variable, check the [execution status of the last command (`$?`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1#section-1). *It contains **True** if the last command succeeded and **False** if it failed*.

Comment: It's commendable to quote with such nice formatting and links, but, unfortunately, the docs are incorrect as of this writing: `$LASTEXITODE` _is_ set in response to `exit $number` calls in scripts in-session, and `$number` _is_ reported as the specific exit code in `-File` CLI calls.

Comment: I've created [GitHub docs issue #10046](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/10046) to get the documentation corrected. I know you're just the messenger here, but I think it's a disservice to future readers to quote demonstrably incorrect documentation without at least pointing out that fact. Happy to revisit  my down-vote if that gets addressed.