# az group delete comes up with ERROR: (ResourceGroupDeletionBlocked) Deletion of resource group 'rg-xxx' failed as '34' resources could not be deleted

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

I have got the Ps script below which gets called in an Azure devops pipeline.

`Message: Deletion of resource group 'rg-xxx' failed as '34' resources could not be deleted. The provisioning state of the resource group will be rolled back. The tracking Id is 'b47axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'. Please check audit logs for more details.`

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
try {
    
  function Get-TimeStamp {   
    return "[{0:dd/MM/yyyy} {0:HH:mm:ss}]" -f (Get-Date)
  }
    
      if ($drop_rg -eq $true) {
    
        $rgExists = az group exists --name $DeploymentResourceGroup 
        if ($rgExists -eq $true) {
          Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp) -  Deleting the resource group $DeploymentResourceGroup "
          az group delete -y -n $DeploymentResourceGroup 
        }
      }
    }
    
      catch {
      
        Write-Host "There has been an error !.`n$_"
        Throw
      
      }
```

My first question is that despite the error above, the pipeline still appeared run successfully. I would prefer if it threw and exception and failed. Not sure why the script is not failing, searching through the raw error logs it appears that it did not get into the catch block.

Secondly, Is there a way to force the deletion of the resource group, I am testing out some IaC and would be creating/deleting resources continuously until I get it working.

Comment: Does it work when deleting manually through azure portal? Maybe you can find more error details inside rg activity log.

Comment: Re your first question: As of PowerShell 7.3.x, calls to external programs _never_ cause PowerShell errors that you can catch (there are selective, _accidental_ exceptions in Windows PowerShell that cannot be relied upon). To detect an external program's failure, you must check if its process exit code, reflected in the automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable is _non-zero_. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67743340/45375) for details.

Comment: As an aside: `$rgExists`, given that it contains the output from an _external program_, is invariably a _string_, so it's conceptually clearer to use `$rgExists -eq 'True'`