# Detect if user cancel call to elevated prompt in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, error-handling, uac

In powershell script is a call to run another PowerShell script using elevated privileges:

```
try{
    powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Start-Process Powershell -Verb RunAs -Wait -ErrorAction Ignore -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"path\to\file`"'"
}
catch{
   # I can't get to here - thats my problem!
}
```

A Windows prompt then asks you: "Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device?".
When accepting, the script runs with elevated privileges, but if the user cancel in this prompt, an error occur.
But in the latter case, I can't catch the cancel. It just gives an error and then continues the script.

Is there by any means a way to catch the error (in the try/catch block), when the user cancel? Here I've put the -errorAction Ignore in the Start-Process, but whatever errorAction I choose I can't catch the error. I've also tried to add an errorAction with the first part of the call (powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -errorAction Ignore ...) with another no-catched error as a result. You can't use the errorAction here ...

Do you have any idea of how to call this script with elevated privileges and catch if the user cancel the Windows prompt?

Comment: What happens when you change '-ErrorAction Ignore' to '-ErrorAction Stop'?

Comment: @Shamus Berube. I've tried all possible values after errorAction: Stop, Continue, SilentlyContinue, Ignore and Inquire. With same result: the RED errormessage.

Comment: @zett42. Your input is very valuable! It allows the program to run correctly. 
Now, I just have to "hide" the error output (to make things looking nice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Calls to *external programs* do *not* integrate with PowerShell's error-handling system**, ***invariably* in *Windows PowerShell* and in [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) *up to version 7.3.x*** and ***by default* in *v7.4+***, so you cannot use [`try` / `catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) with a call to an external program such as `powershell.exe`.

  - Instead, you must manually test for failure via the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode): a *nonzero* value by convention indicates failure, and you can take action accordingly.
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67743340/45375) for details.
- However, **given that you're calling *from PowerShell*, there is no no need to call via [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)**, the Windows PowerShell CLI.

  - That is, unless you're running *PowerShell (Core)* and must explicitly call *Windows PowerShell* - but here, since you need a CLI call *via [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)* `-Verb RunAs` in order to achieve elevation anyway - you're free to choose either CLI executable, i.e. you can alternatively call [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the PowerShell (Core) CLI.
  - If you want to call the *same* PowerShell executable that underlies the *current session*, use `(Get-Process -Id $PID).Path`

```bash
try{
  # Call Start-Process directly.
  # If the user cancels the UAC prompt, a statement-terminating error
  # occurs, which (silently) triggers the `catch` block.
  Start-Process powershell Verb RunAs -Wait -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "path\to\file"'
}
catch{
   Write-Warning "User canceled UAC prompt."
}
```

Comment: Just on the spot. You saved my day and night. I use the call without the call via powershell.exe

Comment: Glad to hear it, @danKV.